# Java caching .wav fails

Tags: java, audio, hashmap, clip

I'm building a piano in Java. I have multiple clips which should be played, and to save RAM, I decided to store them in HashMap for later use. But this fails, it only plays one time, ond one time only. What am Ia doing wrong?

Source:

```
//imports etc.

HashMap<String, Clip> cache = new HashMap<String, Clip>(); //defined as global variable, before the constructor

public void play(String file) {
    Clip clip = null;
    AudioInputStream audio = null;
    if (cache.containsKey(file)) {
        clip = cache.get(file);
    } else {
        audio = AudioSystem.getAudioStream(getClass().getResource("/res/sounds/" + file + ".wav"));
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audio);
        cache.put(file, clip);
    }
    clip.start();
}
```

Note: `String file` is just a name of a .wav, such as `"C4"`, or `"F#5"`. And I repeat once again, this code plays the sound for the first time, but never after.

Comment: *plays the sound for the first time, but never after.* not clear how are you doing it?

Comment: I have a button which calls the function with specific key name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because an `AudioClip` object plays from the last played frame. This isn't reset by calling `start`.

You need to reset it everytime you want to play the clip again.

```
if (cache.containsKey(file)) {
    clip = cache.get(file);
    clip.setFramePosition(0);
}
```

Comment: @MarijanSmetko AFAIK there is no reputation limit to accept an answer. You only have to wait 15 minutes since the time you posted the question to be able to accept an answer

Comment: my bad, i was thinking about something entirely else.